# Animate UIButton with animationImages changes button state fade after animation completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

I am animating `UIButton` with `animationImages` and its animating successfully, but after animation completion the `UIButton` fade out automatically. How can i avoid the fade out?

```
sender.imageView.animationImages =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"main_bird_animation_01%@",ipadVar]],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"main_bird_animation_02%@",ipadVar]],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"main_bird_animation_03%@",ipadVar]],
                                             nil];
        sender.imageView.animationDuration = 1.f;
        sender.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 4.f;
        [sender.imageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: Is this happening inside an IBAction method?

Comment: yes it is happening inside IBAction method

Comment: After animation completion, may be you can try to reset image state? Refer to [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/27/animate-images-uiimageview-completion-handler/) link for completion handler

Comment: i have already read this but this is not proper way, i want to find out reason why it behaves like this

Comment: Have you already setup button image before adding animation images? `[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: yes i added first animation image in `viewdidload` and then in `IBAction` i animate images

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, actually there are is a property Associated with `UIButton` called `Disabled Adjust Image`, I just uncheck and it did the trick.

[image]